# Group actions by inverse limits

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group that is the inverse limit of an inverse system $(G_{i},f_{i})$. Assume that each $f_{i}$ is surjective. If $G$ acts effectively on a topological space $X$, must there be effective actions of the $G_{i}$ on $X$? Note that by an effective action of $G$ I mean that if $g,h\in G$ are distinct elements then there is an $x\in X$ such that $gx\neq hx$.

I am particularly interested in the case where the $G_{i}$ are discrete and the action of $G$ is continuous.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I realized I am really interested in the following question. If a group $G_{1}$ acts effectively on a space $X$ and $f:G_{1}\rightarrow G_{2}$ is a surjective group homomorphism must there be an effective action of $G_{2}$ on $X$?

Comment: If we look at topological groups, so all actions and homomorphisms are continuous, then the question at the end has a negative answer, $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q,\leq)$ with the pointwise convergence topology has the fixed point on compacta property, but it is also the surjective image of some giant discrete free group which acts effectively (indeed freely) on a compact space. I suspect the answer is negative for discrete group too but I don't have an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In particular, you can have $G_1$ act effectively on a space $X$, even though some quotient $G_2$ does *not* have any effective actions on $X$. For example, look at the usual action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by translations. Now $\mathbb{Z}$ surjects onto, say, $\mathbb{Z} / 3$, but there is no effective $\mathbb{Z} / 3$ action on $\mathbb{R}$.

To see why, let's start with $\text{Homeo}(\mathbb{R})$, the group of homeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself. It has an index $2$ subgroup $\text{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{R})$ of *order preserving* homeomorphisms.

Now if $G$ acts effectively on $\mathbb{R}$, we must have an injection $G \hookrightarrow \text{Homeo}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $G \cap \text{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ which must have index $1$ or $2$.
We know $G = \mathbb{Z} / 3$ has no index $2$ subgroups, which means
$\mathbb{Z} / 3 \cap \text{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Z}/3$. That is,
$\mathbb{Z} / 3 \leq \text{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{R})$.
But it's "well known" that the countable subgroups of  $\text{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{R})$ are exactly the countable groups admitting a compatible [left-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group). See for instance, Theorem $2.23$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05088.pdf).

Since $\mathbb{Z} / 3$ has no compatible left-order (indeed, every left-orderable group is torsion free) it cannot act effectively on $\mathbb{R}$.

This same argument will work for basically any group acting on $\mathbb{R}$, as long as it has a quotient that has torsion and *doesn't* have an index $2$ normal subgroup.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.